# What does n mean in big-oh complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

In Big-Oh notation, what does `n` mean? I've seen input size and length of a vector. If it's input size, does it mean memory space on the computer? I see `n` often interchangeably used with input size.

Examples of Big-Oh,

`O(n)` is linear running time
`O(logn)` is logarithmic running time.

A code complexity analysis example, **(I'm changing input `n` to `m`)**

```
def factorial(m):
   product = 1
   for i in range(1, m+1):
      product = product*i
   return product
```

This is O(n). What does `n` mean? Is it how much memory it takes? Maybe `n` mean number of elements in a vector? Then, how do you explain when `n=3`, a single number?

Comment: In this case, where there is actually a variable named `n` in the code, I'd say it's safe to assume that it's referring to that variable.

Comment: It's more confusing here, they are both `n`. But I think `O(n)` and `n` inside the function are different things?

Comment: The runtime of the code you posted is linear in the value of the argument, not its size. So if you interpret `O(n)` to refer to the size of the input in this case, the statement "This is O(n)" would be false.

Comment: Wait what? Why would runtime depend on the value of the argument, say n=3 or n=5? Shouldn't it depend on its size, meaning number of elements in the input vector?

Comment: What input vector? Your function takes a single integer as its argument. And the runtime depends on that value because the number of iterations depends directly on that value.

Comment: Suppose I change n to a vector n =[5, 10, 9, 35], I have a list of numbers waiting to be evaluated. I thought complexity on how many element I have. You are talking about runtime, I'm talking about complexity. Maybe I am confusing runtime vs. complexity?

Comment: I was talking about the runtime complexity. But it does not matter whether we're talking about the complexity or the actual runtime in seconds. Either way it depends on the value of `n`. If you iterated over a vector (which you shouldn't call `n` because that'd be an awful name for a vector), it would depend on the number of elements in that vector. But then we'd be talking about different code.

Comment: I changed `n` to `m` in the function. Now, in the updated code, does `n` refer to the size of  `m`, but `m` doesn't have any size, it's an integer, what's going on here?

Comment: If somebody told me that the updated code's runtime is in `O(n)`, I would be undecided between thinking that it's a type and they meant `O(m)` or they meant the input size and were simply wrong. The code is NOT `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the input (a.k.a. `log(m)`).

Comment: Why would runtime complexity depend on the value of the input, say 3 or 4, not the number of elements in the input, say m=[41, 5, 75, 21,11, 83]. The computer is indifferent to what number I put in, it just does the operation. It's the number of operations that makes an algorithm complexity or not. Ten more elements means 10 times more repeated looping. No?

Comment: If you input a larger number for `m`, the code you've posted will perform more iterations. `for i in range(1, m+1)` will iterate `m` times. If `m` is larger, it will iterate more times. That means more operations.

Comment: If you were iterating over a list, it would depend on the number of elements in the list, but you're not. You're iterating from 1 to `m`, so the number of iterations clearly depends on the value of `m`.

Comment: Ah, that's true too. So, size is referring how large the number is? Why should you call it size? Or don't you call it something like magnitude? Also, doesn't increase the number of elements in a vector also increase complexity? If S is a string, n is NOT len(S)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When somebody says `O(n)`, the `n` can refer to different things depending on context. When it isn't obvious what `n` refers to, people ideally point it out explicitly, but several conventions exist:

1. When the name of the variable(s) used in the O-notation also exist in the code, they almost certainly refer to the value of the variable with that name (if they refer to anything else, that should be pointed out explicitly). So in your original example where you had a variable named `n`, `O(n)` would refer to that variable.
2. When the code does not contain a variable named `n` and `n` is the only variable used in the `O` notation, `n` usually refers to the total size of the input.
3. When multiple variables are used, starting with `n` and then continuing the alphabet (e.g. `O(n*m)`), `n` usually refers to the size of the first parameter, `m` the second and so on. However, in my opinion, it's often clearer to use something like `| |` or `len( )` around the actual parameter names instead (e.g. `O(|l1| * |l2|)` or `O(len(l1) * len(l2))` if your parameters are called `l1` and `l2`).
4. In the context of graph problems `v` is usually used to refer to the number of vertices and `e` to the number of edges.

In all other cases (and also in some of the above cases if there is any ambiguity), it should be explicitly mentioned what the variables mean.

In your original code you had a variable named `n`, so the statement "This is `O(n)`" almost certainly referred to the value of the parameter `n`. If we further assume that we're only counting the number of multiplications or the number of times the loop body executes (or we measure the time and pretend that multiplication takes constant time), that statement is correct.

In your edited code, there is no longer a variable named `n`. So now the statement "This is `O(n)`" must refer to something else. Usually one would then assume that it refers to the size of the input (which would be the number of bits in `m`, i.e. `log m`). But then the statement is blatantly false (it'd be `O(2^n)`, not `O(n)`), so the original statement clearly referred to the value of `n` and you broke it by editing the code.

Answer (score 0):

`n` usually means amount of input data.

For example, take an array of 10 elements. To iterate all elements you will need ten iterations. `n` is 10 in this case.

In your example `n` is also value which describes size of input data. As you can see your factorial implementation will require `n+1` iterations so the asymptotic complexity for this implementation is around `O(n)` (NOTE: I omitted 1 since it doesn't change picture a lot). If you will increase passed variable `n` to your function it will require more iteration to perform for calculating result.

Comment: What's "amount input data", "size of input data"? Does it just mean the number of elements in a list, matrix, or tensor?

Comment: @user13985 Yes, like size of the file to process or number of elements in array or length of text.

Comment: I tend to think size as in memory size, I guess that's where my confusion is. Maybe they should call it number of elements, more straight-forward. :(

Answer (score 0):

O(1) describes an algorithm that will always execute in the same time (or space) regardless of the size of the input data set.

O(N) describes an algorithm whose performance will grow linearly and in direct proportion to the size of the input data set.

O(N^2) represents an algorithm whose performance is directly proportional to the square of the size of the input data set. This is common with algorithms that involve nested iterations over the data set.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think we don't have something like O(2n) in Big Oh notation. We always drop the leading constants and use only significant term , n in this case . Its O(n) not O(2n).